# Parse JSON in an Ansible registered variable to another file

Tags: python, json, ansible

Found the top rated questions for writing the register variables to a file but the trouble that i'm having is grabbing each IP address from an array and just writing those to a file. For example:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "environment": "p", 
            "guest_os": "Linux", 
            "location": "sjc", 
            "vsphere_password": "username!", 
            "vsphere_username": "password"
        }
    }, 
    "result": [
        "10.44.100.100", 
        "10.101.111.100", 
        "10.101.112.130"
     ]
```

is an example of my output. I am creating an array named `result` and putting it in the `exit_json()`

```
module.exit_json(result=json.loads(json.dumps(result_list, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)))
```

Just want to grab all the IPs so I can use it as a host file. I could edit my module to create an actual JSON instead of just creating an array of IPs if it would be easier to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out!

I ended up using the filter `ipaddr` from ansible then using the `replace()` functions

```
    local_action: copy content="{{ json_hosts.result | ipaddr | replace('[','') | replace(']','') | replace(',', '') | replace('"', '') | replace("'", '') }}" dest=/path/
```

really ugly unless there's a better way